# How to determin minimum samples to consider to obtain nearly same average as all samples?

Tags: statistics, logic, average

I would like to know if there is any standard algorithm or statistical parameter than can be used to determine how many minimum samples should be considered from beginning whose average value  nearly matches with the average of all samples.

For Example : If 2000 samples are present and Average is 20
Acceptable  average range is   20+-0.01
If we start taking average from  first sample  then by taking average of X samples we can get average within 20+-0.01

Problem is about find value of X
Just need guidance from logical perspective [Procedure or Algorithm to consider]
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is, but I think we need more information about how values in your population are distributed. Are the distribution a standard distribution with mean 20? If so, what is the standard deviation? Is it a uniform distribution? If so, over what range of values? Once the distribution is specified fully, the procedure will be to choose a confidence interval... like 95%, for instance ... and find the sample size N such that the probability of the average of N individuals from the population being in the range [19.99, 20.01] is at least 95%. Sadly, 100% confidence is not realistic.

Comment: You can consider total deviation for all samples within 19 to 21

Comment: Can you suggest considering standard distribution of sample points with 95 percent confidence ?

Comment: So if you just want me to choose a standard deviation for the purposes if illustration, that is fine - I can choose 1, which would mean 68% of samples are in the range 19-21, 95% are in the range 18-22 and 99.7% are in the range 17-23. The calculations would look the same with a different standard deviation, just with different numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so if the standard deviation is known, then for a 95% confidence that the sample mean will be within 0.01 of the true mean for a normal distribution with standard deviation equal to s, we require that:

```
0.01 = z95 x s / sqrt(n)
```

Here, z95 is the two-sided CDF of the normal distribution and is about 1.96 (from tables), s is the standard deviation and n is the number of samples required. We can solve for n in terms of s:

```
    0.01 = 1.96 x s / sqrt(n)
<=> sqrt(n) = 196s
<=> n = 38416s
```

So, if s = 1, you'd expect to need about 38.5k samples to get a 95% confidence that the sample mean would be within 0.01 of the true mean. The number of samples needed to achieve a given precision is directly proportional to the true sample standard deviation.

If the true population's standard deviation is not known, the calculation works in a similar fashion, except you would use the CDF from the student's T distribution (so instead of z95 you'd use t95) and you'd use the sample standard deviation.

If you want a different confidence interval - higher or lower - you'd look up the corresponding two-sided CDF for whichever distribution you're using and use the corresponding value (so something besides 1.96).

The discussion on Wikipedia, Basic Steps section, is instructive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval